# Symfony2 generate CRUD with NetBeans IDE 8.0

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

I am using NetBeans IDE 8.0 and just start learn symfony2. I try to generate CRUD but I get message

```
The CRUD generator expects the entity object has a primary key field named"id" with a getId() method.
```

but when  check in my `entity` file I see

```
    private $userid;

    public function getUserid()
       {
              return $this->userid;
       }
```

Any one can share it to me, how to fix it? 
I am don't know what my problem! I am looking to see your reply soon!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add mapping metadata to your field `$userid` (if it is your primary key). If you use annotations for mapping you need to add `* @ORM\Id` in the annotation block above `$userid` field.

See more here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys

Comment: So what `format` that i need to choose? yes i really choose `annotation`

Answer (score 0):

When creating an entity, the entity should have attribute `$id`, `getId()` and `setId($id)` methods and correct mapping information, it could be for example like this:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="your_entity")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class YourEntity {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    public function setId($id){
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

If you want to rename your column name from `id` to for example `user_id` you change it by setting `Column` annotation `name` attribute, like this:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
 private $id;
```

Comment: After I modify field name in my database and modify in my `entity` file as your example above but i still get problem like `                 [ReflectionException]                                               
  Property login\loginBundle\Entity\Register::$userid does not exist` or it's has any place for me to change any more ??

Comment: @Time Try to delete cache.